# Change default zoom in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, zoom, default-settings

I don’t understand how default zooming works in LibreOffice. For example, I like it to default zoom at 100%. One time I accidentaly zoomed (when trying to select lots of rows) and after that immediatly <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and I opened a new spreadsheet zoomed to 150%.

When I closed it, and entered another spreadsheet file, it opened with 150% zoom. And it happens all the time, even if I reduce to 100%, save file and open it again, it still opens with 150% zoom and it does when creating new with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. How can I set it back?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like LO saves zoom with the document.
I tried in 4.4.0, and it opened a Write document with the zoom it has been saved and closed.
LO did the same with Calc.

I tried to edit the default Write template and set a zoom and save and close -- but it did not work: a new document did not inherited the zoom with the template.

Still LO 4.4.0 does not saves the page display setting: the document was closed with single page view and opened with double page view -- but with the saved zoom value.
I hope it helped.